# Admin login to user accounts

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, admin

I have a pretty simple login script which does as you would expect and checks for a match in the database between an Email and Password combination. Although I am wondering if there is a way that I could edit this script so an Administrator could use a users email like such:

`user@hotmail.com`

And a master password or something:

`master123`

To access any account on the system? Here is my current script:

```
<?
session_start();
    require_once("system/db.php");

    if($_POST['submit']){

    $email_address = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email_address']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $stay_logged_in = $_POST['stay_logged_in'];


 if (empty($email_address) === true || empty($password) === true) {
     header('Location: login.php?loginerror=3');    
 } else {

    $sql1 = "SELECT * from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
    if (!$result1->num_rows == 1) {
        header('Location: login.php?loginerror=4');
    } else {


    $sql2 = "SELECT * from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' AND blocked='0' LIMIT 1";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if (!$result2->num_rows == 1) {
        header('Location: login.php?loginerror=6');
    } else {


    $sql = "SELECT * from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' AND password = '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        header('Location: login.php?loginerror=2');
    } else {

        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_users SET last_login = NOW() WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}'");

        if($stay_logged_in == 1){
            setcookie("email_address", $email_address, time()+31556926 ,'/');
        } else {
            setcookie("email_address", $email_address);
        }




$length = 76;
$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
$hash = md5($randomString);
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_users SET login_hash = '{$hash}' WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}'");
if($stay_logged_in == 1){
setcookie("hash", $randomString, time()+31556926 ,'/');
} else {
setcookie("hash", $randomString);   
}
    $value = 'yes';
    if($stay_logged_in == 1){
    setcookie("login", $value, time()+31556926 ,'/');
    } else {
    setcookie("login", $value); 
    }
    header('Location: check_gateway.php');

    } 
    }
    }
    }
    }
?>
```

I have tried adding:

```
if($_POST['password'] != 'master123'){

$sql = "SELECT * from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' AND password = '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        header('Location: login.php?loginerror=2');
    } else {

} else if($_POST['password'] == 'master123'){
```

Which didn't quite do the job? Any ideas ?

Comment: You want to use a master password for all user? so that admin can logged in as any user by using master password?

Comment: I can't really think of a more secure way to do it, users all have a `user_level` of `4` but admins have a `user_level` of `2` or `1` in the database, if that may be any more secure?

Comment: create a column `master_password` along with password and give it a default value like `123456`, now do the query like:- `$sql = "SELECT * from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' AND (password = '{$password} OR password = '123456')' LIMIT 1";
   `

Comment: A side note: the `md5()` hashing function delivers weak hashes and is _not_ suited to be used for password protection.

Comment: @arkascha rather than the md5 option, is there another way to encode passwords which would be more secure?

Comment: Certainly, there are a few hash algorithms available. A simple google search will show them. Easiest is to use php's builtin password handling functions. And please don't confuse the terms "hashing" and "encryption" :-)

Comment: @Snappysites sha1() + salt (arbitrary salt or user related like email+password+arbitrary) does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `master_passowrd` column in user table than do a query like that.

```
select * from user where `email` = '$email' AND (`password` = '$password' or `master_passowrd` = '$password')
```

Comment: While this works and everything, and I appreciate the help, would this be a secure way to do this?

Comment: I dont know you application architecture so I can not suggest the best one.

Comment: Having a unique password for every user is not, indeed, a good way to secure. The best way to access users data or users actions is to access them from an Admin panel. It is slightly different to 1/ login as root to use data/actions as user, 2/ to login as user and you should consider that.
For exemple, make an Admin panel where you can do actions (create DB entries, news, products...) as a user, and read/write user datas.

Comment: @tomsihap yes I do agree with you. But I dont know his application architecture and operation. I just give him an idea to logged in user account via master password

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is pretty simple and doesn't require a master password.

Admin users run off a different set of cookies and session which allows me to login as an admin, from the admin side I can select which user I'd like to login as and create their cookies and session on the fly. This is beneficial because:

1. You always know if it was an actual admin user who logged in and/or the changes made  because youll have 2 sets of cookies etc.
2. I can check multiple users with ease without having to log out of being an admin and when I want to change user I just replace the cookies / session info for the users side.
3. It also adds an extra layer of security as users will not know what the admin cookies are named (hopefully)

If you dont want to do that, just create the users session by calling the DB and getting the email and pass and creating the session, no masterpassword neeeded.

I normally double hash passwords either

sha1(md5($password)) or

md5(sha1($password)) or

md5(md5($password))

Not sure if this will help you.

EDIT: If you want to login with their username create a form on your admin side eg:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="user_login_admin">
 <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" placeholder="Enter User Email">
<input type="submit" name="user_temp_login" id="user_temp_login" value="Admin User Login">
</form>
```

Then your new login script will be:

```
 <?
session_start();
    require_once("system/db.php");

    if($_POST['submit']){

    $email_address = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email_address']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $stay_logged_in = $_POST['stay_logged_in'];


 if (empty($email_address) === true || empty($password) === true) {
     header('Location: login.php?loginerror=3');    
 } else {

    $sql1 = "SELECT * from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
    if (!$result1->num_rows == 1) {
        header('Location: login.php?loginerror=4');
    } else {


    $sql2 = "SELECT * from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' AND blocked='0' LIMIT 1";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if (!$result2->num_rows == 1) {
        header('Location: login.php?loginerror=6');
    } else {


    $sql = "SELECT * from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' AND password = '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        header('Location: login.php?loginerror=2');
    } else {

        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_users SET last_login = NOW() WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}'");

        if($stay_logged_in == 1){
            setcookie("email_address", $email_address, time()+31556926 ,'/');
        } else {
            setcookie("email_address", $email_address);
        }




        $length = 76;
        $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
        $hash = md5($randomString);
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_users SET login_hash = '{$hash}' WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}'");
        if($stay_logged_in == 1){
        setcookie("hash", $randomString, time()+31556926 ,'/');
        } else {
        setcookie("hash", $randomString);   
        }
            $value = 'yes';
            if($stay_logged_in == 1){
            setcookie("login", $value, time()+31556926 ,'/');
            } else {
            setcookie("login", $value); 
            }
            header('Location: check_gateway.php');

    } 
    }
    }
    }
    }elseif($_POST['user_temp_login']){
    $email_address = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']);
        $sql = "SELECT password from ap_users WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}' LIMIT 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
                // no email address
            }else{
                $length = 76;
                $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
                $hash = md5($randomString);
                mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE ap_users SET login_hash = '{$hash}' WHERE email_address = '{$email_address}'");
                if($stay_logged_in == 1){
                setcookie("hash", $randomString, time()+31556926 ,'/');
                } else {
                setcookie("hash", $randomString);   
                }
                    $value = 'yes';
                    if($stay_logged_in == 1){
                    setcookie("login", $value, time()+31556926 ,'/');
                    } else {
                    setcookie("login", $value); 
                    }
                    header('Location: check_gateway.php');
                    }    
    }
?>
```

You actually don't even need to select the password because the hash doesn't contain the password. BUT if someone logs into their account while you are logged in, you will probably be booted from the session as the hash will change.

The script can still be optimised (also is not 100% secure the way it is) and you should really be using a PDO or Mysqli. This will stop SQL injection, even though you have used real_escape_string it is still possible to do SQL injection.

Comment: A lot of good advice there, thanks very much! To go ahead with that style of system, would take a lot of editing on my admin panel. I may upgrade in the future to be able to do it like that as it seems a lot more secure! If you could keep your answer up so I can refer to it later, that would be great!

Comment: No problem, and of course! It's normally a lot easier to implement from the beginning. 

I quick solution at present would be to create a small form on your admin side where you can input the users email and still use the same file you have there, just use something different than submit, Ill send my answer with a quick version.